# Derivation of theorems using axioms

Tags: proof-verification, logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, axioms

How to derive this $$\vdash\forall y_1\dots\forall y_n B\to B$$?

**Attempt**

I tried to see for only one variable, that is $\vdash\forall y_1 B\to B$.

Proof: By hypothesis $\forall y_1 B$ and by A4 axiom I can have $\forall y_1 B\to B$. Using modus ponens in both formulas I have B.

When I tried to add another variable y$_2$ a question appear: $\forall(y_1y_2)\iff\forall y_1\forall y_2$?

If both are equivalent, then $\forall( y_1\dots y_n)B\to B$ by A4 and by hypothesis $\forall( y_1\dots y_n)B$. Using Modus ponens in both formulas I get B.

Am I correct ?

Note: A4 is the axiom 4, you can see them here:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, forget modus ponens for the single variable case. You are deducing from the empty set, so the proof of the single variable case $(\forall y_1) B \rightarrow B$ is just that it's an instance of A4.

It's not usually the case that $\forall(y_1 y_2)$ is even a valid thing to write down formally, although its intended meaning is clear. And its intended meaning is the same thing that $\forall y_1\forall y_2$ means. It seems like you're trying to group $y_1$ and $y_2$ into "one thing" and just apply your previous method to it, but I don't think that's the right thing to do formally.

Instead we can do it inductively. By A4, we can deduce $\forall y_1 B \rightarrow B$ and we can also apply A4 on the formula $\forall y_1 B$ to deduce $\forall y_2 \forall y_1 B \to \forall y_1 B.$ Then we can combine these two formulae to deduce $ \forall y_2\forall y_1 B\to B.$ It should be intuitively clear that this is valid, but I'll leave the details to you.

Comment: How did you obtain $\forall y_2\forall y_1 B\to B$?

Comment: @Michelle Deduction from $\forall y_2 \forall y_1 B\to \forall y_1 B$ and $\forall y_1 B\to B.$  A case of the more general result that from $A\to B$ and $B\to C$ you can deduce $A\to C.$ I left it as an exercise to show this formally (and honestly one of the drawbacks of of Hilbert style systems is that even 'obvious' things like this can be confusing to show at first). I'm guessing you can find it hunting around in your book / notes but otherwise my hint would be to use the deduction theorem.

Comment: Like transitivity, I guess I can use the result.

Comment: Well it's hard to say what the 'right' answer is for your course / book's development. Informally, yes, it's 'transitivity of implication' but logic is about playing by the rules and the most direct way that principle shakes out of the formalism can vary. My suggested way is contingent on having the deduction theorem. We have $A, A\to B, B\to C \vdash C $ from two applications of MP. Then from the deduction theorem $A\to B, B\to C \vdash A\to C. $ But if you already have that last result  at your disposal, go ahead and use it.

Comment: A = $\forall y_2\forall y_1B$ and I can state it as hypothesis right?

Comment: Right. That's the route using the deduction theorem. You add $A$ to the left of the turnstyle, derive $C$ and then that implies there's a derivation of $A\to C.$

Comment: $\forall y_i\iff\forall y_1,y_2,...,y_n$?

Comment: Or $\forall y_1,...,\forall y_n$?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. In most formal first order logic systems, the comma is not a valid character. A statement that universally quantifies over two (or several) variables is generally written something like, for example, $$\forall y_1\forall y_2 (y_1+y_2 = y_2+y_1).$$ I have no idea what you're getting at with $$\forall y_i \iff \forall y_1,\ldots,y_n.$$ $\forall y_i$ is just something that quantifies over one variable... $y_i.$ The RHS is, as I said, something that I doubt is even valid syntax in your system, although I would guess it means the same as $\forall y_1\ldots \forall y_n$

Comment: I was trying to involve all the n variables the get the complete result, I think I did it.